# What does the %in% operator do inside an R lm formula?

Tags: r, lm

The docs [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/formula.html) say:

> The %in% operator indicates that the terms on its left are nested
> within those on the right. For example a + b %in% an expands to the
> formula a + a:b.

But I don't know what they mean by "nested", and I'm confused because the %in% operator is already defined to do element-wise membership test?

What does it do? What is the point? Please give an example.

Comment: That statement from the help file just means `lm(mpg ~ cyl %in% am, data=mtcars)` is the same as `lm(mpg ~ cyl:am, data=mtcars)`

Comment: Nesting is a statistical procedure. You should be asking on http://stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: @IRTFM the question was just migrated then stats stack exchange rejected it because "It is a programming question" (according to them).

Personally I am inclined to agree with you,
but also I think the question is a little bit of both.

Comment: Those jerks. Why can’t they just explain nesting? I’m not sure about this but my fuzzy memory is that @thelatemail is incorrect. The colon operator in formula generates interactions. Nesting is involved in partitioning sums of squares. But I would need to look up the exact difference in a stats book.

Comment: Here's a webpage using Inchanter as the statistical platform that demonstrates both interaction terms and nesting and makes an effort to distinguish them: https://saturncloud.io/blog/stepbystep-procedure-for-nested-logistic-regression-in-incanter/#:~:text=Interaction%20terms%20are%20variables%20that,other%20variables%20in%20the%20model. Voting to reopen since the CV.com people seem unable to recognize the fact that the question was about the meaning of nesting.